# Make cron log work again?

Tags: linux, cron

I wanted to clean the cron log in /var/log so I delete it with `rm cron`.

Then I created a new file with `cat > cron`, but no logs are being stored in that file.

I don't know how to see cron logs again.

The server is with CentOS and the file has permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      0 sep  6 09:42 cron
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that your original `/var/log/cron` file is open for writing by a daemon which is most likely syslogd or rsyslogd. The file will still be open and will still be in use.

Find the PID of your syslogd | rsyslogd then use

```
sudo kill -HUP <PID>
```

this should cause the file to be flushed and closed and a new one opened.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using `top` to list processes but I can't find it. I don't know how to show all the list that is truncated at the window height. I'm connecting through SSH Secure Shell.

Comment: @Memochipan: `ps -ef | grep syslog`

Comment: Thanks I obtained: root      1291     1  0 Aug31 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/rsyslogd -c 4
gdm       1917     1  0 Aug31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
root     18133 17431  0 11:11 pts/0    00:00:00 grep syslog------------------------Then I wrote sudo kill -HUP 1291 and it worked! Again I see the logs! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

And the root:root ownership may be the problem. It has to be owned by the user/group running cron. Look at another CentOS machine and set the ownership with `chown user:group /var/log/cron`.

Maybe you have files named `cron.0`, `cron.1` in `/var/log` and you can copy the ownership from them.

Comment: Thanks this is what I have in the other cron files of the same Machine: -rw-r--r--   1 root root      0 sep  6 09:42 cron
-rw-------   1 root root 175071 ago 14 03:35 cron-20110814
-rw-------   1 root root 174786 ago 21 03:19 cron-20110821
-rw-------   1 root root 176033 ago 28 03:44 cron-20110828
-rw-------   1 root root 175302 sep  4 03:38 cron-20110904

Comment: In other CentOs this is what I have: -rw-------   1 root root    56609 sep  6 10:30 cron
-rw-------   1 root root   167611 ago 14 03:08 cron-20110814
-rw-------   1 root root   169034 ago 21 03:24 cron-20110821
-rw-------   1 root root   168223 ago 28 03:33 cron-20110828
-rw-------   1 root root   169105 sep  4 03:14 cron-20110904

Comment: So then @Iain is right. Restarting of the log deamon (or in worst case the server) will do the trick.